# Routing in react using spa-github-pages - unable to send '/' and '/about' requests to About component

Tags: reactjs, url-routing, single-page-application

Using react-spagithubpages to publish this app to Github pages and I want my About component to answer calls for "/" and "/about" however I can only get it to show on one, a couple of attempts had the component duplicated on one page, or not at all.

Here's what I have:

```
App.js
<div className="container">
  <Header />
</div>

Header.js
<Switch>
  <Router>
    <Navbar >
      <Navbar.Brand>
        <Nav id="NavItem" style={brandStyle}>
          BRAND
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar id="navButton">
        <Nav style={aListStyle}>
          <Link to="/about" id="NavItem" style={aStyle}>About.</Link>
          <Link to="/resume" id="NavItem" style={aStyle}>Resume.</Link>
          <Link to="/contact" id="NavItem" style={aStyle}>Contact.</Link>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar>
      <Route exact path="/" component={AboutComponent}/>
      <Route path="/about" component={AboutComponent}/>
      <Route path="/resume" component={ResumeComponent}/>
      <Route path="/contact" component={ContactComponent}/>
    </Navbar>
  </Router>
</Switch>
```

And I've tried variations of the following:

1.

```
  <Route path='/' component={App}> // tried replacing App with {AboutComponent} or {Home}
    <IndexRoute component={AboutComponent}/>

    <Route path='/about' component={AboutComponent}/>
    <Route path='/resume' component={ResumeComponent}/>
    <Route path='/contact' component={ContactComponent} />
  </Route>
```

2.

```
<Router>
    {["/", "/about"].map(path => 
        <Route path={path} component={AboutComponent} />
    )}
</Router>
```

3.

```
<Router>
    <Route path="/(about|*|/)/" component={AboutComponent} />
</Router>
```

4. Making my own routes.json file to no avail

The last thing I can think to do is to duplicate the AboutComponent and make a separate HomeComponent to send '/' requests to.

**Edit:** Vishal Sharma suggested using Redirect and it works.

```
<Redirect from='/' to='/about'/>
```

Comment: do you really need to have 2 routes pointing to the same component? if you want same component to be shown for 2 different routes, You can use redirects. example: `<Redirect from="/" to="/about"/>`

Comment: I was following the docs and working within their scope. The Redirect method works. Thanks.

Comment: Adding that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments and conclusions, there is not really a need of writing a separate route if the rendering component is same. In my opinion, `Redirect` serves better.

Example:
`<Redirect from="/" to="/about"/>`